# Instant search filter with pagination using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for pagination on this http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/filtered-attendees-list
 please
help me..

I want to implement like this "page":

[image]

Code is available on the link

Comment: please give more details

Comment: Include some code ....